# How do I enable design mode on child components that have no name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a WinForms C# UserControl that will function like a Delphi PageControl (a panel that swaps between multiple pages, but only one page is visible at a time). I want the user to be able to drop components onto a page at design time.

I have it mostly working, but am having trouble with the serialization. I'm using a List for my pages and am serializing out this list like so:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<Panel> Pages { get { return _pages; } set { _pages = value; } }
```

And I allow the user to interact with the panels using a custom Designer descended from ParentControlDesigner. I have the Designer call a SetDesigner method of the PageControl and the PageControl stores a reference to the designer so that it can call EnableDesignMode on any panels it creates.

My problem is, EnableDesignMode's name parameter. I'm not sure what to put there. These panels are elements of a List and don't have names that can be referenced by pageControl1.Name. I've tried setting the names to "Pages[0]", "Pages[1]", etc. but that crashes during serialization.

Any ideas on how I should handle this? Long story short: How can I have a dynamic list of child panels that the user can interact with at design time and have the designer remember the settings and child controls on these panels?

**Edit**
To be more clear about what I'm trying to do, I want to create a UserControl that acts as a Panel, but has multiple "pages". When the user changes its PageIndex property, it switches to an entirely different Panel and the user can add different controls. Something that could be used for a wizard or something where one panel could have multiple views.

Comment: Are you trying to add anonymous controls and want to move, resize, add and remove them? You need to be clear about what you want to do.

Comment: I edited my post to (hopefully) add some clarity.